# propositional-calculus/logic riddle

Tags: propositional-calculus

Two physicists, A and B, and a logician C, are wearing hats, which they
know are either black or white but not all white. A can see the hats of B
and C; B can see the hats of A and C; C is blind. Each is asked in turn if
they know the color of their own hat. The answers are: A:"No." B: "No."
C: "Yes." What color is C's hat and how does C know?

I could not figure this one out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A is the first to answer.  Since he said no, that means B and C don't both have white hats.  This leaves 6 possible cases (in order ABC).

WWB

WBW

WBB

BWB

BBW

BBB

Now, WBW is easy to exclude.  If B sees two whites, then he knows his must be black.

Also we can exclude BBW.  For, if A didn't know, but B sees black and white, he knows that he must be black, (for then A would know, as he would see two whites).

The only possibility then is that C has a black hat!